# Find Efficient way of Filtering of two arrays (ArrayA & ArrayB) to make a third ArrayC

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects

Can anyone help me come up with a faster way of filtering the following `ArrayC` (see below what it should be equal to. `ArrayA` is self explanatory. `ArrayB` has inside of each element an object `'data'` that has a property `"target"` as a string `"\_teacher"` that I can filter out based on a global variable `"userType"` to distinguish students vs teachers. `"filter_klas_1371" ==> filter_{GroepType }_{GroepID}` from Array A. This property changes. breaking the string and filtering has giving me a headache, so if there are faster more efficient ways to filter this please let me know.

```html
let userType='teacher'

arrayA: [{
    "ID": 1,
    "GroepID": 1371,
    "GroepType": "klas"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "GroepID": 1372,
    "GroepType": "klas"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "GroepID": 1375,
    "GroepType": "graad"
  }
]

araayB: [{
"id": "bd5b12ba-b433-4610-801e-e0b78fa72ff8",
    data: {
      "target": "_teacher",
      "filter_klas_1371": "true"
    }
  },
  {
  "id": "gggfdgdba-gfgg-fff-ggg-7657657676",
    data:{
      "target": "_teacher_student",
      "filter_klas_1375": "true"
    }
  } {
  "id": "uuuykllk-b433-4610-801e-8888888776",
     data: {
      "target": "_student",
      "filter_klas_1372": "true"
    }
  } {
"id": "jkjkjkklk-jkhjk-66567-666-99977",
    data: {
      "target": "_teacher_student",
      "filter_klas_1372": "true"
    }
  },
  {
   "id": "zzzzzzz-b433-4610-801e-8888888776",
    data: {
      "target": "_teacher",
      "filter_klas_1372": "true"
    }
  },
]

//should get
arrayC:[{
"id": "bd5b12ba-b433-4610-801e-e0b78fa72ff8",
    data: {
      "target": "_teacher",
      "filter_klas_1371": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
    "id": "jkjkjkklk-jkhjk-66567-666-99977",
      "target": "_teacher_student",
      "filter_klas_1372": "true"
    }
  },
   {
     "id": "zzzzzzz-b433-4610-801e-8888888776",
    data: {
      "target": "_teacher",
      "filter_klas_1372": "true"
    }
  }
  ]
```

Comment: Your results are inconsistent in form in this example

Comment: More efficient than what? Where is your attempt? Additionally, you're not expressing the filtering criteria. In other words, we don't know when an item inside C should be filtered out.

Comment: mark, the filterinf occurs in klas = 1371 and 1372 for "_teacher" type. hence the 3 values in array c. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct you would like to filter arrayB based on the userType and the values in arrayA. I suggest making an array of all the possible `filter_{groepType}_{groepId}` with array map:

```
const filterKeys = arrayA.map(group => `filter_${group.GroepType}_${group.GroepID}`);
```

Then you can check if one of those values is set as a key in the keys of arrayB, using an intersection of array with a couple of filters. You can do this in more ways:

```
arrayC = arrayB.filter(item => {
  const intersect = Object.keys(item.data).filter(key => filterKeys.includes(key));
  return intersect.length > 0; // you can additionally add the filter for target here
})
```

Comment: Thanks John I used your logic with some tweeks to get it to filter correctly.